# Rails order by associated object number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-order-by

The title of this question might be a bit off but its the closest I could get to what I am trying to do.

I have a Products model which has_many Comments.  I am looking to come up with a way to grab the top 10 Products with the most comments.  Is this possible?

At the moment I have:

```
Product.find(:all, :limit => 10)
```

This gets me my 10 products, but it obviously does not consider how many comments each product has.

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a counter cache column on Product for Comment then you can do this with a simple `:order_by` on that column.

**Edit:** Taking animal's comment into account:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments,
    :counter_cache => true
end
```

You will need a column on `products` called `comments_count`:

```
add_column :products, :comments_count, :integer, :null => false, :default => 0
```

Comment: You'll also need to change the belongs_to in Comment to belongs_to :product, :counter_cache => true

Comment: That's true. I was just describing the general principle.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you don't want to alter your model you can use find_by_sql to specify a subselect which will tell you how many comments each product has and order by that. E.g.

```
Post.find_by_sql("SELECT products.*
  FROM products, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM comments WHERE comments.product_id = products.id) AS product_comment_count
  ORDER BY product_comment_count DESC
  LIMIT 10")
```

You might need to adjust the syntax to be specific to whichever RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Product.all(:select=> "products.*, COUNT(products.id) AS comments_count",
            :joins => :comments, 
            :group => "products.id", 
            :order => "comments_count",
            :limit => 10)
```

Result is sorted by the comment count and you can access the `comments_count` as follows:

```
@products.each do |product|
  p product.comments_count
end
```

Make sure you have indexed the `product_id` column in the `comments` table.

**Note:**

I would use the `counter_cache` feature for this requirement(as suggested by `@tadman`).